# SQL Azure and CDN

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, global, replication, latency

what is the best way to limit latency for SQL Azure in global applications?
My Application uses SQL Azure and would like to know based on the network location of users if its possible to connect SQL Azure near to users.

So Logically would need to have SQL Azure database with global replication but not geo-replication as each copy would serve as Master and not secondary.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try CosmosDB to distribute data globally and obtain low latency as explained on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cosmos-db-microsofts-globally-distributed-multi-model-database-service/) article and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/distribute-data-globally) documentation.

For replicating data using SQL Data Sync with Azure SQL Database, take in consideration [paired regions](https://buildazure.com/2017/01/06/azure-region-pairs-explained/) which may reduce latency. With SQL Data Sync a hub database can be defined and many member database on another region, and data can be synched on both ways between the hub and any member database.